# Old version of Azure application Insights performance profiler for which application?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-application-insights-profiler

I have an Application Insights in Azure. There are some ASP.NET web applications deployed in Azure virtual machine which sends data to that Application Insights.

The problem is when I am going to 'Configure Application Insights Profiler' (under 'performance' tab and then 'configure profiler') in the Application Insights, it is showing me a message 'We detected one or more of your apps are using an older profiler agent. You must be on latest agent to get the new trigger-based profiling feature. [Click here to learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-settings)'.

[image: We detected one or more of your apps are using an older profiler agent. You must be on latest agent to get the new trigger-based profiling feature.]

When I am going to the link it is asking to check Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) extension version in the virtual machine location 'C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics'.

I have created a list of applications which are having the INSTRUMENTATION KEY in their web.config of the particular Application Insights. I logged into each of the virtual machines where those applications are deployed and checked the location. All of them are having the latest Windows Azure Diagnostics (WAD) extension installed on them.

At this point I have no idea about the reason of the message. Can you tell me, is there a easy way to check for which application it is showing the message?

Answer (score 0):

Hi @DeveloperArnab are you still facing this issue? This is usually caused by one of your applications being on an older version of the agent or one of the apps sampling out application insights telemetry

Comment: @Steve: While it does start off with a question, it's also proposing a solution. (I'm not certain if it's a _correct_ answer or not, as I haven't run into this issue, but that's obviously what the voting mechanism is for.)

Comment: Yes, I still have this issue. I know the reason of the message. But as I told in my question that, I already checked all my applications which are connected to the particular Application Insights. But I failed to find out the application which is having older version of agent.